# What is wrong with the CTE syntax in this Sql Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone explain why Sql Server is complaining about the syntax around the "WITH" clause?

Thanks for any help.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable1 (
    Id int not null,
    Version int not null constraint d_Ver default (0),
    [Name] nvarchar(50) not null,

    CONSTRAINT pk_TestTable1 PRIMARY KEY (Id, Version)
);
GO


CREATE TRIGGER trg_iu_UniqueActiveName
ON [dbo].[TestTable1]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF(UPDATE([Name]))
BEGIN
    IF(
        ( 
            WITH MaxVers AS
                (SELECT Id, Max(Version) AS MaxVersion 
                FROM [dbo].[TestTable1]
                GROUP BY Id)
            SELECT Count(1) 
            FROM [dbo].[TestTable1] t
                INNER JOIN MaxVers ON t.Id = MaxVers.Id AND t.Version = MaxVers.MaxVersion
            WHERE t.[Name] = inserted.[Name]
        )
        > 0
    )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @name nvarchar(50)
        SELECT @name = [Name] FROM inserted;
        RAISERROR('The name "%s" is already in use.', 16, 1, @name);
    END
END;
GO
```

Edit 2: 
For anyone who is curious, here is the CTE version that incorporates all of the great comments below.  I think I will switch to the sub-query approach so that I can use the "EXISTS" as suggested.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_iu_UniqueActiveName
ON [dbo].[TestTable1]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF(UPDATE([Name]))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cnt [int];
    WITH MaxVers AS
        (SELECT Id, Max(Version) AS MaxVersion 
        FROM [dbo].[TestTable1]
        GROUP BY Id)
        SELECT @cnt = COUNT(1) 
        FROM [dbo].[TestTable1] t
            INNER JOIN MaxVers ON t.Id = MaxVers.Id AND t.Version = MaxVers.MaxVersion
            INNER JOIN [inserted] i ON t.[Id] = MaxVers.[Id]
        WHERE t.[Name] = i.[Name] AND NOT [t].[Id] = [i].[Id] ;
    IF( @cnt > 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @name nvarchar(50)
        SELECT @name = [Name] FROM inserted;
        RAISERROR('The name "%s" is already in use by an active entity.', 16, 1, @name);

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END
END;
GO
```

Edit 3: Here is the "Exists" version (Note, I think that the select in the error handling part would not work correctly with more than one inserted record):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_iu_UniqueActiveName
ON [dbo].[TestTable1]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF(UPDATE([Name]))
BEGIN

    IF(EXISTS (
        SELECT t.Id 
        FROM [dbo].[TestTable1] t
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT Id, Max(Version) AS MaxVersion 
                FROM [dbo].[TestTable1]
                GROUP BY Id) maxVer
                ON t.[Id] = [maxVer].[Id] AND [t].[Version] = [maxVer].[MaxVersion]
            INNER JOIN [inserted] i ON t.[Id] = MaxVer.[Id]
            WHERE [t].[Name] = [i].[Name] AND NOT [t].[Id] = [i].[Id]
        ))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @name nvarchar(50)
        SELECT @name = [Name] FROM inserted;
        RAISERROR('The name "%s" is already in use by an active entity.', 16, 1, @name);

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END
END;
GO
```

Comment: Why not move the the CTE select expression to an sub select in the inner join? And you should use `EXISTS` instead of `Count > 0`

Comment: ) > 0 .... um ... are you comparing a CTE to 0 ?

Comment: Your trigger is not written to properly handle multi-row updates as evidenced by `SELECT @name = [Name] FROM inserted;`

Comment: id is identity column? then why you need group by id?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "identity" EricZ.  It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can use CTEs with inner queries.

Use this as workaround:

```
DECLARE @cnt int;
WITH MaxVers AS
    (SELECT Id, Max(Version) AS MaxVersion 
    FROM [dbo].[TestTable1]
    GROUP BY Id)
SELECT @cnt = Count(1) 
FROM [dbo].[TestTable1] t
    INNER JOIN MaxVers ON t.Id = MaxVers.Id AND t.Version = MaxVers.MaxVersion
WHERE t.[Name] = inserted.[Name];
IF @cnt > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(50)
    SELECT @name = [Name] FROM inserted;
    RAISERROR('The name "%s" is already in use.', 16, 1, @name);
END
```

Comment: It looks like you are correct about it not allowing the WITH in that location.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can figure is that the statement "[When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175972%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)" (Transact SQL Reference) means that a CTE can not be used within an IF statement.

BTW, you have two other errors: 1) `inserted` pseudo table is not included in the first sub-query, even though you reference it in the were clause. 2) Your trigger is assuming a single row is being inserted or updated. It is possible that there would be multiple duplicate names but the raiserror will only report one of them.

**EDIT** And avoid `(select count(*) ...) >` when `exists (select * ....)` will do The exists can stop at the first row.

**EDIT 2** Crap. SQL Server trigges default to after triggers. So the row you are checking for existence on already exists in the table when the trigger fire:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_iu_UniqueActiveName
ON [dbo].[TestTable1]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF(UPDATE([Name]))
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS 
        ( 
            SELECT *
            FROM [dbo].[TestTable1] t
                INNER JOIN inserted i on i.[NAME] = t.[NAME]
                INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, Max(Version) AS MaxVersion 
                    FROM [dbo].[TestTable1]
                    GROUP BY Id) MaxVers ON t.Id = MaxVers.Id AND t.Version = MaxVers.MaxVersion
        )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @name nvarchar(50)
        SELECT @name = [Name] FROM inserted;
        RAISERROR('The name "%s" is already in use.', 16, 1, @name);
    END
END;
GO

insert into testTable1 (name) values ('Hello')
```

results in:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_iu_UniqueActiveName, Line 20
The name "Hello" is already in use.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Plus, the raiserror does not perform a rollback, so the row is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to like the `WITH` statement inside an `IF` does it.

Try the following SQL instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM TestTable1 t1
WHERE t.Name = (SELECT [Name] FROM inserted)
AND t.Version = (SELECT MAX(Version) FROM TestTable1 t2 WHERE t2.Id = t.Id)
```

Much simpler in my opinion. This doesn't account for multiple rows in the inserted table however. Change it to an `IN` rather than an `=` would probably do that.

As others have noted sometimes putting a semi-colon in from of the `WITH` statement works, but I couldn't get it to in this instance.